# HTML: Make Title and Tab Different

Tags: html, title

I'm making a web site for a friend's company Redevelopment Reporting Solutions (RRS) and obviously that would be the title of the page. Unfortunately, in the tab bar Redevelopment Reporting Solutions is cut off. So, basically I want to have it say RRS in the tab, while still saying Redevelopment Reporting Solutions in the title bar at the top. I know they are both the title property so I don't know if this is even possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean the browser tab bar or Windows task bar?  Either way I think the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The browser will automatically make them both the same, there's no way to change that functionality via your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

My work-around to this would be to make the favicon.ico display RRS, and let the logo in the page do the explanation.